# New (.NET Core) C++/CLI project has compile issues when definition and implementation are split

Tags: c++-cli, visual-studio-2019

I created a `"CLR Empty Project (.Net Core)"` project using Visual Studio 2019.

I simply created a new class using the 'add class' menu option and it generated this class.
I added the function called `Test` in the header:

```
using namespace System;

public ref class Class1 {
    // TODO: Add your methods for this class here.

    void Test();
};
```

Then using visual studio's generate implementation option it created this function defenition in the .cpp file:

```
#include "EngineEditorLayer.h"

#include "pch.h"

void Class1::Test() { throw gcnew System::NotImplementedException(); }
```

When compiling it gave me this error :

`error C2653: 'Class1': is not a class or namespace name`

I can only resolve this error by moving the implementation to the header file.

Am I missing something? Is there a setting I have to change to enable .cpp compilation? 
Is there a compiler bug that prevents me from doing this currently?

Comment: You ought to get a warning for this code, easy to miss when you focus too much on the error.  pch.h must be #included first.  The compiler skips anything  until it finds it, so the #include for EngineEditorLayer.h doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hans Passant from the comments was right. The pch.h has to be included first.

I unfortunately never got the warning. This was my output log:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: EngineEditorLayer, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>EngineEditorLayer.cpp
1>E:\Other Projects\PixEngine\EngineEditorLayer\EngineEditorLayer.cpp(7,18): error C2653: 'Class1': is not a class or namespace name
1>Done building project "EngineEditorLayer.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

Comment: I repro, no warning.  Well sugar.  It does explain why the more common VS2019 project templates dropped pch.